# Bootstrap modal height and width is not getting accurate

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal but the problem is that the bootstrap modal is not properly aligned according to the forms. Please find the screenshot of

[image: Screenshot of the live website]

And here the code is :

```css
.modal.fade .modal-header {
  background-color: rgba(131, 72, 172, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" style="display:none;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" align="center">Quick Enquiry</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please fill up the form for Quick Enquiry.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="span12">
          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="email_format.php">
            <input type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="name" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
            <br>

            <input type="email" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="website" placeholder="Website">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="msg" placeholder="Questions?">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p style="font-size:11px; line-height:20px;"> <input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp; &nbsp; I accept <a href="terms.php" target="_blank">SEO_Faceup Terms & Conditions</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" name="questions" class="thm-btn b-inner font-8">Submit</button></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>


<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a></div>
```

And I tried  to reduce the width of the modal by css using `.modal { width: 350px; }` but the popup is not coming in center.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? `.span*` was from the 2.x and depreciated in 3.x.  You're also using `.col-*-*` but no `.row` which may account for the additional left/right padding if that is the alignment issue you mention.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly, add `style="width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;"` to the `.modal-body` class. On a side note, i recommend that you use classes instead of inline styles.

```css
.modal.fade .modal-header { background-color:rgba(131,72,172, 0.8); color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" style="display:none;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 320px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" align="center">Quick Enquiry</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <p>Please fill up the form for Quick Enquiry.</p>
<div class="span12">
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="email_format.php">
           <input type="text"  style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="name" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
<br>

          <input type="email" id="reqDate"  style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Email"required>
<br>
  <input type="text" id="reqDate"  style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="website"  placeholder="Website">
<br>
          <input type="text" id="reqDate"  style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
<br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate"  style="height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="msg"  placeholder="Questions?">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p style="font-size:11px; line-height:20px;">  <input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp; &nbsp; I accept <a href="terms.php" target="_blank">SEO_Faceup Terms & Conditions</a>.</p>
    </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="submit"  name="questions" class="thm-btn b-inner font-8" >Submit</button></div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

    </div></div>
    </form>
</div>


 <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a></div>
```

Comment: Okay but the popup is still big i want the popup to be of same size

Comment: I have updated in main code but the text box in center but the pop is still have bigger in size

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and remember HTML is your friend ;)

```css
.modal.fade .modal-header {
  background-color: rgba(131, 72, 172, 0.8);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" style="display:none;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" align="center">Quick Enquiry</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><center>Please fill up the form for Quick Enquiry.</center></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<center>   
<div class="span12">
          <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="email_format.php">
            <input type="text" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="name" value="" placeholder="Full Name">
            <br>

            <input type="email" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="website" placeholder="Website">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="reqDate" style="width: 300px; height: 40px;" class="form-control" required name="msg" placeholder="Questions?">
<center>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p style="font-size:11px; line-height:20px;"> <input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp; &nbsp; I accept <a href="terms.php" target="_blank">SEO_Faceup Terms & Conditions</a>.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" name="questions" class="thm-btn b-inner font-8">Submit</button></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>


<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a></div>
```